# In Google Analytics > User Explorer > Search For User

Tags: google-analytics

I am simply trying to search for a certain user based on their `Client Id`.  How Can I find a particular user like `129237576.1471287532` to view their 
`User Report`.

Secondly... how could I search all users for a pattern.  So instead of numbers.numbers - search numbers_numbers - so 129237576.1471287532 vs. 14756_7856.

Comment: Client id is not exposed by google analytics its only used for internal processing.  save it as a custom dimension and search on that if you need to.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because does not appear to be programing related may be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/